# Building for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, build

I am a web programmer and I work mainly with ruby on rails and javascript jquery, and so on.

Now I would like to build a program for mac.
Which languages ​​do I need? C++, Objective C?

For info and good beginner tutorials I would be very grateful.

Comment: web programming is independent of OS. Which program you want to make?

Comment: yes
really that's why I ask for.
no specific
Eventual enough for the beginning a hello world program in a windowless
but no dos window
something simple to start

Comment: @CevinEichnau : Based on user1203613 question, I don't get what you meant... Can you tell me what program you want to make?

Comment: a hello world programm is a simple programm wich the text "hello world " in a window show ...but I do not care what kind of a program
any program
the main thing I'm learning how to program for osx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best tutorials that I have seen on programming particular to the Mac OS X environment are:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programming_Mac_OS_X_with_Cocoa_for_Beginners
http://www.youtube.com/user/AppleProgramming

Also if you like to read books, the tutorial books from Big Nerd Ranch are quite good:

http://www.bignerdranch.com/books

Especially check out the "Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X (4th Edition)" book.

Comment: You are welcome; I hope that these references help you on your journey to learn how to work with the particulars of Mac OS X.

Comment: There are also the free resources from Apple. Assuming you have a Mac, you should (1) download Xcode (free) from the Mac App store; (2) start reading the included documentation; (3) poke around [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com), [register as a developer](https://developer.apple.com/programs/register/) for better access (it's free). The docs are all included in Xcode but also available online. Try this one:  
[Start Developing Mac Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/chapters/01_Introduction.html) - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could use any language you like. My recommendation will be `Java` since it can be learned very easily and `OS X` comes with java pre-installed. However for Mountain Lion, you'll have to install java by yourself.

See

- [`Easy Java Tutorial` - my tutorial on java](http://easyjavatutorial.weebly.com)
- [`Oracle Java Trails`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)
- [`JavaLessons.com`](http://javalessons.com/)
- [`Learn Java in a Day`](http://www.roseindia.net/java/learn-java-in-a-day/index.shtml)

Comment: Sorry Cevin, this is not good advice. Do NOT learn Java for programming the Mac. The native language is Objective-C, which is a superset of C. So you should learn C first - not to expert level, but you will need to have a __basic__ grasp of pointers and the C type system from the outset. A set of fantastic hands-on guidebooks are published by Big Nerd Ranch. A good starting books are "Objective-C Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide" (which includes the C you need) and "Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X". These will give you a good grounding even if you go on to do iPhone apps.

Comment: ah okay thank you for information ... i have an start my "programmer kariere " lear a little bit c++ ... thats help for learn c and c objecktive ?

Comment: @Cevin - yes, learn C (but don't get too distracted by the minute details) then Objective C. The details of C you can pick up while learning Objective C so don't spend too long on pure C! It's really the same language, Objective-C adds some syntax for messaging and objects on top of C. If you are reading OSX code, as a __rough__ guide everything you see in `[square brackets]` or `@starting @with @` is objective-c, the rest is standard C.